# Azure Mobile App with service layer

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, service-layer

In MVC web applications we tend to use architectures with multiple layers.
I like to use a service layer which encapsulates the business logic and has the data access layer etc. below.

The service layer, can be used by multiple frontends.

Since azure mobile apps are using `TableController` which provide CRUD opertions on database tables or DTOs, there is no way to use the service layer.

**Are there any approaches on how to use azure mobile apps in large business applications with multi layer architectures?**

Comment: As far as I know, the mobile service backend is still a web api. The server SDK also use the EF to CRUD.If you want to use service layer, you could create your own controller to CRUD the data.But the SDK provide multiple operation like offline sync and so on, you need accomplish the operation by yourself.

Comment: That is the point. Is there any way to connect offline sync, conflict handling and so on with a multi layer architecture.